# Spring : annotations for @Configuration class

Tags: java, spring

I'm new to SpringBoot, and I don't quite understand for example this class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(...)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {...})
@Import(SomeClass.class)
public class MyConfig {

     @Bean
     public IFactory myFactory(IService myService){
          return new myFactory(myService);
     }
     ...
}
```

1. Why we are using `@ComponentScan` here ? The moment Spring detects this configuration it should include everything annotated with `@Bean` inside no ?
2. What does the `@Import` do here ? Why should be import a class rather than annotate it inside with `@Bean` ?
3. Is there any relation bewteen `@Bean` and the classes under `@ComponentScan` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. @ComponentScan scans for other @Configuration/@Component/@Service/etc. annotated classes, under e.g. the basePackages you specify. It has nothing to do with the @Beans *inside* your configuration.
2. @Import explicitly imports another @Configuration, with all its @Bean definitions.
3. Having methods annotated with @Bean and @ComponentScan (searching for Java classes that are annotated with e.g. @Component) are two different ways of achieving the same thing: registering @Bean definitions/creating @Beans.

Comment: and if we @Import a controller ? what does it mean ?

Comment: so basically these three annotations do one thing : register beans ? So if I understand correctly, @Configuration is used for registering beans ?

Comment: You wouldn't really @Import a controller. The three annotations are all used to declare beans, yes.

Comment: If you want to have an more detail description, check out this article (which I wrote) https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-framework . it goes into detail about all the different ways of how to register beans etc.